# How to send a KeyEvent if a gesture is detected

Tags: android, gesture, keyevent, d-pad

I want a gesture D-Pad, but how can I send an e keyevent if I detect a gesture? For example, I detect the gesture down, and now I want to send the keyevent `KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN`.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send the key event only to your application, the easiest is to just inject it in the root view:

```
KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(...)
someView.getRootView().dispatchKeyEvent(event);
```

If you want to send it to another application/window, then you cannot (you would need a special permission, which requires you to have your application signed with the system certificate, AFAIK)